# Exceeded the Permitted Memory

Tags: gap

I have been trying to program with large matrices, but unfortunately I have been getting an error that my permitted memory has been exceeded. I have read various ways online that it is possible to increase the permitted memory using Command Line Options (e.g. -m 4g), but GAP keeps saying there are syntax errors. I run GAP with Windows and am not the most technologically savvy. Can someone give me step by step instructions on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you using the command line options? From your exposition, it almost sounds like you are not putting `-m 4g` in the right place -- it sounds like you're putting it *in* your GAP code, rather than adding it to the command that launches GAP.

Comment: This is not the right place for this question.  It is software, not mathematics.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing exactly what you're saying. Where's the correct place for this?

Comment: @RossMillikan: Ostensibly, questions about [software that mathematicians use](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is explicitly on topic.

Comment: @spadey plesase see `gap` tag description for suitable places for such questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gap/info

Answer (score 1):

To launch a windows program with command line arguments, you need to first create shortcut to it, and then open up the properties of that shortcut so that you can add them to the target. You can then use the modified shortcut to launch your program with the desired options.

[Here is a question](https://superuser.com/q/29569/409120) from another stackexchange site about the correct syntax. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good reference question on stackexchange for the general question, but you should be able to google to get more information if this and that isn't helpful enough.

(or even post the general question about adding command line arguments over at https://superuser.com)

Comment: The standard GAP for Windows provided by the .exe installer is 32-bit, and one can't get more than 4g with it (and 4g is default setting). One may try to use the experimental 64-bit version, can be downloaded from http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/